# Xcode sigabrt (lots of questions about this no answers work)

Tags: xcode, calculator, sigabrt

So there are a lot of threads like this but no answers work for me.  So, I am using Xcode 4.2 and on Single View Application with storyboard enabled.  It is giving me the sigabrt error!

I am making a calculator of sorts, Called Cool calc.

GO TO http://pastebin.com/awmizYJQ FOR MY .H and .M INFO

**IN MY OUTPUT IT SAYS**

```
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1708) (Mon Aug  8 20:32:45 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".Attaching to process 1185.
2012-06-20 14:11:37.556 storyboardcoolcalc[1185:f803] Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
```

EDIT: I FORGOT TO ADD THE MOST IMPORTANT INFO..... The sigabart info is available at
imgur.com/yzCSS

Comment: Please give more infos about the SIGABRT location. It should show in Xcode debugger view.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Questions here should be as complete and concise as possible,  which means they should be narrowed down to a manageable amount of code and the code should be included here as part of your question. Expecting people to leave this site, wade through your code to try and figure out what might be wrong, and then come back here to answer. You might want to take a few moments to review the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), especially the part about how to ask a question to improve your chances of getting an answer. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Ken I know, I accidentally took out the sigabrt info when I realized that I couldn't add images. I will edit my post with the sigabrt info